# Stored procedure cannot insert into column name Timestamp

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, timestamp, sql-insert

I am trying to write a stored procedure to insert into an `email` table. In my `email` table, I have the time-created column named timestamp. I did not know timestamp was a SQL keyword. How would I fix this? Thank you (I don't want to change the column name because I have a lot of SQL statements to edit)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[btbSe]
    @SenderId int,
    @SqlReceiverId int,
    @EmailSubject varchar(max),
    @EmailBody varchar(max),
    @DateTime varchar(50)
AS
    INSERT INTO Emails (SenderId, ReceiverId, EmailSubject, EmailBody, Timestamp) 
    VALUES (@SenderId, @SqlReceiverId, @EmailSubject, @EmailBody, @DateTime, GETDATE())
    RETURN 0
```

Comment: Yes, of course, ideally objects that you create in SQL Server should not be named the same thing as reserved keywords - but, really, many people do it.  Just wrap the word Timestamp in square brackets - ie. [Timestamp] - and you'll be OK

Comment: By the way, you still have a lot of SQL statements to edit ..... so maybe it is a worthwhile exercise to change the column name.

Comment: Appreciate your help thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap such columns into the double quotes as follows:

```
..
..
INSERT INTO Emails (SenderId, ReceiverId, EmailSubject, EmailBody, "Timestamp") 
VALUES
..
..
```